# Insert into select in particular column

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How to (insert into select) and make WHERE work for insert and not for select? I want to insert values where student_id=? not select where student_id=?

```
            String aa=model.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();;
            String sql="INSERT INTO evaluation (rank) Select Rank from evaluation Where student_id=?";
            try {
                PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps1.setString(1, aa);
                if(ps1.executeUpdate() > 0)
                {


                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Evaluation Done");
                }


            }
             catch (Exception ee) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Your idea makes no sense and wouldn't work. You select all ranks from evaluation and want it to put it where exactly. The select statement works like INSERT INTO evaluation (rank) VALUES (1),(2),(3)..... so you can't put it in to one row

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert into an existing row. INSERT, by definition, creates new rows. If you want to change existing rows, use UPDATE, not INSERT.